# ionic 3 bind ID to <ion-textarea>

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

is it possible to bind an ID to a ion-textarea ?

Like:

```
<ion-textarea placeholder="Enter your thoughts" id="thoughtsBox"></ion-textarea>
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you trying to set the focus to the element with that id?

Comment: Yes, like this `document.getElementById('thoughtsBox').focus();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can do it. The way u have used it is correct.

Comment: I tried this and my App crashed on function call: `document.getElementById('thoughtsBox').focus();` I get this Error with Logcat: `chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(56113)] "[WARN] TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (56113)`

Comment: I have used this:-

Try Using this this might work for you as well:-

setTimeout(() => {
                    document.getElementById('broadcast-textarea').focus();
                    Keyboard.show();
                }, 750)

Comment: @MrFlyingToasterman Try using it and let me know if it does not work

Comment: Do I have to import something for the keyboard? Atom does not find Keyboard .. Could you perhaps write me a small sample code? I'm not yet experienced with Ionic and TypeScript.

Comment: import { Keyboard} from "ionic-native"; write this in import section